# How to make a second form appear on top of the main form at start?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms; My main Form named `Form1` and my second Form named `Form2`

My main form shows up at start, and I'd like to show `Form2` too but it shows up under `Form1`.
And I want it to show up on top of my main form.

I've tried to set `Form2`'s `TopMost` property to `true` then `false` but it didn't work.
I also tried to create a different Thread for `Form2` to appear after `Form1`, in this case `Form2` shows up quickly then disappear.

Comment: `TopMost` should have worked actually, but only as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show `Form2` in `Shown` event handler of `Form1`:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

You can use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` if you want `Form2` to be modal.

Comment: +1. Never knew about the `Shown` event. Although I am not sure why this works without having to specify ownership, something like  `form2.Show(this)`. Is it a feature of layout order, that it by default creates form on top of the last created form in the project?

Comment: @Neolisk yes, windows are ordered according to their appearance on the screen. [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) method is used for setting Z-order of form when it is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at Form1 load event:

```
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.TopMost = true;
            form2.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want Form2 to be TopMost. I just want it to show up on top of Form1 at startup.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Form2().ShowDialog()
```

This will also lock Form1 until Form2 gets closed

Comment: Thank you. This is a valid answer but I don't want Form1 to be locked. Thank you still.

Comment: please would mind to show us how to pass parameter from `Form1` to `dialog` or from `dialog` to `Form1`?

Comment: @sam `var f2 = new Form2(parameters); f2.ShowDialog(); result = f2.Result;`